# How to avoid overflow in finddropdown flutter

Tags: flutter, overflow

Hello everyone i've made a map with 2 dropdowns, they work but i got this issue i cant seem to get rid of.

When the names of the selected items are too long i get an overflow.

I dont know what to do about it, hope someone can help me with this :)

Widget:

```
Theme(
                                  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                                    primaryColor: azulTuti,
                                    accentColor: azulTuti,
                                    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                                        primary: azulTuti),
                                    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
                                        textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
                                  ),
                                  child: FindDropdown(
                                    searchBoxDecoration: InputDecoration(
                                        hintText: "Seleccione un local"),
                                    selectedItem: selected_local,
                                    items: locales,
                                    key: UniqueKey(),
                                    onChanged: (local) {
                                      if (local != "Seleccione un local") {
                                        setState(() {
                                          selected_local = local;
                                          chooseLocal = true;
                                          zoomMarker(selected_local);
                                        });
                                      }
                                    },
                                  )),
```

What i get:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define `dropdownBuilder`. Please add the following code inner `FindDropdown` Widget.

```
dropdownBuilder: (context, selectedItem) {
  return Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
        color: Colors.white),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            selectedItem.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 8),
        Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
      ],
    ),
  );
},
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna use this it will keep your text in one line and scrollable

```
                    Expanded( 
                      child: Container(
                         child:SingleChildScrollView(
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            child: Text(
                              "--",),
                         ),
                      ),
                    )
```

Comment: Your answer worked but i prefer Mardel's answer, 1+ cause was useful :)